# Express - custom Content-Type when using res.render() and swig engine

Tags: express

I'm using `Swig` to render `JSON` templates in `Express`.

I included the following middlewares:

```
app.engine('json', require('swig').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'json');
app.set('views', app.get('templates_dir'));
```

However, when rendering my templates I get `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`.

It's there an easy way to customize http headers when using my json engine declared above?

Or should I inevitably bootstrap `res.render()` and set the header manually or just create another method like `res.renderJSON()` (what I'm trying to evade)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm not certain whether res.render will try to set the content-type header a second time:

```
function setJsonHeader(req, res, next){
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  next();
};

// apply the middleware to all routes, before your router:
app.use(jsonMiddleware);
app.use(app.router);

// or instead, apply it selectively:
app.use(app.router);
app.get('/api/*, setJsonHeader);
app.get('some/other/json'
, setJsonHeader
, function(req, res, next){
  var data = {foo:'bar'};
  res.render('aJSONTemplate', data)
});
```